# Estudiar con método práctico la POO con Python

Tags: python, poo

Tengo grandes dudas acerca de la POO, la entiendo bastante, creo; pero no acabo de comprender como implementarla en un programa, o sea, todos los ejemplos que encuentro en los cursos, tanto de pago como gratis, hablan de la clase *Coche*, la clase *Gato*, y otras clases que no le encuentro mucha utilidad práctica.

Necesito algún curso  de como implementar bien el tema de los objetos, clases, en proyectos reales, o sea, como usarlos e implementarlos en un programa, ya que no se me ocurre un programa que necesite tener un clase *Gato*, o *Coche*, a no ser que sea para un concesionario o una tienda de animales.

Entiendo el tema de las clases y objetos pero no como manipularlos en un programa

Gracias a todos y espero aprender mucho con vosotros

Comment: Sólo aprenderas haciendo. Estudiar la teoría es la partida, pero sólo resolviendo problemas podras internalizar los conceptos y dominarlos. Ni 100 horas de clases lograra lo que hacen 10 horas de práctica; es la práctica lo que hace al maestro. No desesperes, parte con cosas simples.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he editado el texto inicial, ya que parece que he quebrantado 1000 leyes del foro.

Comment: Vaya, no queria picar Enter. Lo que necesito saber es que una vez creadas las clases, con sus métodos y atributos, como interactuo con ellos en un programa real. O sea, vale, tengo la clase gato para una tienda de animales, pero ¿Como la uso? Un programa estructurado es facil, accedo a una función y la uso, pero a la hora de la POO no encuentro en ningún sitio como trabajar a la practica con los objetos e instancias. Se que necesito práctica, pero si no se ni por donde empezar es complicado practicar. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Gran razón en lo que dices, te planteo un escenario **Pedidos a Domicilio** en donde pienses en lo siguiente:

- ¿Quienes sujetos intervienen en el proceso de pedidos?
- ¿Que eventos suceden al hacer un pedido de los cuales deseas guardar datos?

Veamos entonces que sujetos intervienen:

- Proveedores
- Productos
- Despachadores
- Motoristas

Que eventos suceden que no son acciones de los sujetos?

- Compras
- Ventas
- PagosEmpleados
- Devoluciones
- Reclamos

Entonces desde el punto de vista de la OOP estas serian tus clases y tendrías que luego definir las propiedades y metodos de cada clase.

No te puedo compartir como tal un enlace de algo así por que no lo he visto en un curso básico, ya que esto involucra que cuando piensas en un Proveedor tienes que programar sus métodos para guardar en una base de datos, modificar, ver pedidos pendientes etc.

Con esto solo trato de darte una idea de lo que puedes hacer con las clases en un entorno real. Piensa en las clases como **Los elementos que intervienen(se mueven) y cooperan en un sistema de información estos elementos no solo pueden ser sujetos tambien pueden ser eventos de los cuales nos interese guardar información valiosa como en el caso de las ventas**.

Espero ayudarte a aclarar un poco el tema.

Comment: Claramente la redacción de la pregunta esta mal, pero el problema esta expuesto ha implementado la clases Gato, Coche y demas y ve que esto sea aplicable a un contexto de una problematica. Entonces pide ejemplos reales del Uso de OOP. Yo comprendo su problema debido a que soy maestro y se que se llega a esos extremos sin sentido de explicar la OOP son cosas claramente fuera de lugar.

Comment: Comprendo tu punto @BetaM esperomos que el OP haga la mejora.